# AngularJS sorting using JSON keys with spaces

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Through my AngularJS application I make calls to an API that return JSON in the following format:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "01"
Contact Name: "Michae"
Phone Number: "2000000000000"
```

As it is shown keys in JSON have spaces, so I used the following code in my app template to display the json content:

```
<select ng-model ="sortorder">
  <option selected value="{{contacts['Contact Name']}}">Name</option>
  <option selected value="{{contacts['Phone Number']}}">Contact Name</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>    
<div ng-repeat="contacts in mContactsList | orderBy:sortorder">
  <p>Contact Name: {{contacts['Contact Name']}}</p><br>
  <p>Phone: {{contacts['Phone Number']}}</p><br>
</div>
```

In controller, I tried using:

$scope.sortorder = 'Contact Name';
and 
$scope.sortorder = '{{contacts[\'Contact Name\']}}';

but none worked...

The problem I am having now is that sorting is not working at all, so can someone please help me by pointing out what exactly I am doing wrong / missing? Any example is highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to define a custom `orderBy` -- remember that it takes a function with your current repeated `contact` as the parameter. Try:

```
$scope.sortorder = function (contact) {
    return contact["Contact Name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
array = orderBy(array, function(row){return row[predicate]}, reverse);
```

- array: is the array you need to sort
- predicate: is the property. It can have spaces, special characters
- reverse: whether you want to sort in reverse order or not